# Drools rule engine Usage-Handling Huge data

Tags: java, jboss, drools, rule-engine

I have a case where i getting packets from a device and inserting that data in a MySQL table.There are 4000 devices and from each device i am getting packets in every two minutes.Each packet data need to  monitor and do some database operation.So i am planning to use drools for monitoring packets and applying different rules.My doubt is drools is capable of handling this much huge data?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use [jpcap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/) to capture packets.

JpCap used to capture network packets. You have to unzip it and it is a DLL file and you should paste it in windows/system32.

Comment: i think he's talking about processing the captured data, not the capturing itself

Comment: @radai..u are correct..i am asking about processing data..not capturing

Comment: @vmb 

JPCAP
    A tool for real-time network traffic capture and analysis
    An API for developing packet capture applications in Java

Comment: i already using another framework for inserting data and that works well